# Proper manual OS setup on LUKS encrypted drive with non-aes algorithm on yum-based distro (CentOS)

Tags: luks, initramfs, disk-encryption, initrd, cryptsetup

I'm trying to achieve LUKS-encrypted CentOS 7 install with separate `/boot` partition and lvm on EFI-friendly motherboard.

I've done partitioning fresh CentOS install from old CentOS(installed from GUI) and it looks like this:

```
sdb             8:16   0 745,2G  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0   200M  0 part  /home/user/target/boot/efi
├─sdb2          8:18   0     1G  0 part  /home/user/target/boot
├─sdb3          8:19   0   700G  0 part  
│ └─crypto    253:3    0   700G  0 crypt 
│   ├─lv-swap 253:4    0    16G  0 lvm   
│   ├─lv-root 253:5    0    50G  0 lvm   /home/user/target
│   └─lv-home 253:6    0   634G  0 lvm   /home/user/target/home
```

Bootstrapping also succeded in CentOS chroot (used [this](http://geek.co.il/2010/03/14/how-to-build-a-chroot-jail-environment-for-centos) and [this](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/ManualInstall) tutorials) and now ready to generate boot image.

The matter is that I've decided to use non-standart algorithm in cryptsetup:

```
cryptsetup -v --cipher serpent-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha256 --iter-time 3000 --use-random luksFormat /dev/sdb3
```

and now I wonder how to to generate correct initrd with my parameters.

Tutorials tell me that the next step is:

`mkinitcpio -p linux` however there is no `mkinitcpio` command or `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` to change `HOOKS` list in order to `lvm` and `encrypt` work correct.

However, there is only `initrd` that is unfamiliar to me due to lack of knowledge about rpm-based distros. Search of initrd examples for my case was out of luck.

Now there are several files/directories in `/boot` inside chroot:

```
bash-4.2# ls
config-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64  grub2                                     symvers-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64.gz
efi                                initramfs-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64.img  System.map-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
grub                               lost+found                                vmlinuz-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
```

But I doubt that they are support serpent encryption or even luks as soon as these files were generated during bootstrap.

So, my question is how do I make correct boot toolchain with luks and serpent starting from kernel image generation?

Though maybe I should use `initramfs` instead of `initrd`, so any hints about this approach is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've finished set up and ready to share finite instruction set of how its done for CentOS 7.

I've skipped partitioning and manual bootstrapping - there are plenty complete manuals elsewhere.

So, start having this partitioning variant:

```
sdb             8:16   0 745,2G  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0   200M  0 part
├─sdb2          8:18   0     1G  0 part
└─sdb3          8:19   0   700G  0 part  
  └─crypto    253:3    0   700G  0 crypt 
    ├─lv-swap 253:4    0    16G  0 lvm   
    ├─lv-root 253:5    0    50G  0 lvm
    └─lv-home 253:6    0   634G  0 lvm
```

then, mount necessary drives, so it becomes:

```
sdb             8:16   0 745,2G  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0   200M  0 part  /home/user/target/boot/efi
├─sdb2          8:18   0     1G  0 part  /home/user/target/boot
└─sdb3          8:19   0   700G  0 part  
  └─crypto    253:3    0   700G  0 crypt 
    ├─lv-swap 253:4    0    16G  0 lvm   
    ├─lv-root 253:5    0    50G  0 lvm   /home/user/target
    └─lv-home 253:6    0   634G  0 lvm
```

---

Step 0. Prepare chroot script. Repeating `mount`'s every reboot is tedious so I've end up with this elementary chroot script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount /dev/mapper/lv-root /home/user/target
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /home/user/target/boot
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/user/target/boot/efi
sudo mount --bind /proc /home/user/target/proc
sudo mount --bind /dev /home/user/target/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /home/user/target/sys
sudo chroot /home/user/target /bin/bash -l
```

Step 1. Install missing EFI-specific modules (outside chroot):

```
sudo yum --installroot=/home/user/target install -y efibootmgr grub2-efi-modules
```

Step 2. Edit `/etc/crypttab`

`crypto UUID=UUID_of_/dev/sdb3 none luks,discard`

Reason for `discard` - I'm using ssd and neglecting a bit of security for better TRIM performance. [Details](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard.2FTRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_.28SSD.29).

Step 3. Edit `/etc/dracut.conf`

```
omit_dracutmodules+="systemd"
add_dracutmodules+="crypt lvm" #sequencing could matter
hostonly="yes" #optional
lvmconf="yes"
```

Step 4. Edit `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=UUID_of_/dev/sdb1                      /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077  0 0
UUID=UUID_of_/dev/sdb2                      /boot           ext2    defaults    0 0
UUID=UUID_of_/dev/mapper/lv-root            /               ext4    defaults    0 0
UUID=UUID_of_/dev/mapper/lv-home            /home           ext4    defaults    0 0
UUID=UUID_of_/dev/mapper/lv-swap            none            swap    sw          0 0
```

Step 5. Edit `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=lv/swap vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 vconsole.keymap=us rd.luks.options=discard rd.luks.uuid=UUID_of_/dev/sdb3 crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=lv/root rd.lvm.lv=lv/home nomodeset"
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub2/themes/system/theme.txt"
```

`rd.luks.options=discard` - may be redundant, correct me if it is.

`nomodeset` - to eliminate hw driver concurrency (noveaufb vs EFI VGA)

Step 6. Execute `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Step 7. Execute `grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi`

Step 8. Execute `dracut -fv`

All above steps need to be done inside chroot unless otherwise stated.

Turned out that encryption algorithm chosen not influenced in any way - grub have all needed drivers loaded automatically.

Here are materials that helped me: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263696/guide-for-gentoo-setup-with-full-disk-encryption-using-lukslvm), [2](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=50535), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/697439/documentation-about-rd-lvm-rd-luks-and-rd-md-kernel-boot-parameters), [4](https://superuser.com/questions/902539/luks-partition-automount-fails-at-boot), [5](https://jfearn.fedorapeople.org/fdocs/en-US/Documentation/0.1/html/Fedora_Multiboot_Guide/GRUB-configuration.html)